# Spyder iPython console stuck at "Connecting to kernel..."

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, spyder

I am running Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine. When starting Spyder, the iPython console is stuck at "Connecting to kernel...". This appeared after my vacation - before the vacation I downgraded Spyder because the Python input() function was broken in the latest Spyder version. However, the following issue seems to appear no matter of which Spyder version I am using (currently 5.2.2).

On the other hand, if ipython is started from conda prompt it works fine.

I have tried the following suggestions that I found in multiple similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but to no avail:

- Completely removing Anaconda and installing latest version.
- Downgrading pyzmq to version 16.0.3 (this fails, Solving environment: failed)
- Updating pyzmq to latest version
- Updating ipykernel to latest version
- Running `spyder --reset`

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is really silly, but it seems like rebooting the computer fixed it.

Comment: lol. It is funny.

Answer (score 0):

When I was setting up custom Anaconda environment to use an older Python 3.6, I encountered the same issue.

The following worked for me.

Select Tools Menu > Select Preferences > Select Python Interpreter >
Select radio button 'Use the following Python interpreter:'

Use browsing icon and navigate to folder that points to your Python executable to set the textbox value. If you aren't sure where the python path is located. Then open a Command Prompt window and type 'where python'. Then choose your specific path from the output - copy and paste to the textbox mentioned above.

Click Apply > Click OK

Next

Select Tools menu > Select PYTHONPATH Manager
Remove any/all paths found
Click Close

The above directions resolved my issue. Beforehand I also tried the following functions listed below. It is possible that the following helped to partially resolve it too.

Open Command Prompt window

- conda activate myenvironment
- conda install spyder-kernels
- conda update pyzmq
- conda update ipykernel

Close Command Prompt window > Reload Anaconda.Navigator
Select myenvironment > Open Spyder